# Huge calls made to ViewRoot.draw()

Tags: android, performance

I have an activity which has some text views and other data to be updated every second.

The performance is sluggish and when i capture the logs and view in TraceView.
  I see at lot of calls been made to ViewRoot.draw() function.

25 calls in a short span of 4 seconds, almost 6 calls every sec.
  Ideally speaking it should be once call every sec.

As per my initial speculation i beleive it is due to the bad layout of my xml, is this true?

How do i identify what is the reason for so many calls?
  which is the best way to reduce these calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these TextViews have their layout_width set to WRAP_CONTENT, then changing the text will trigger a measurement pass as their size will have changed. That could certainly get expensive. Try making them fixed-width.

Comment: If there are eight text views in my layout, with all of them being wrap_content, changes the content of these would trigger eight seperate re-rendering or will it intelligently be multiplexed to one single call where all the text views are changed?

Comment: Keeping mind of the important thing, what you just mentioned, what are the other general guidelines that should be followed to reduce the number of calls to Re-rendering ?                                       Also i see a lot of calls being made to Android.dispatch message() nearly 75 calls in 4 secs, apart from triggered by user inputs how to detect who else is triggering these many calls?

Comment: TraceView should show you exactly what's calling what. How about pasting your layout XML here? Also, 75 UI thread messages in 4 seconds doesn't sound bad to me... perhaps you are optimizing in the wrong place? Where does traceview say the the greatest %age of exclusive CPU time is?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the layout below,

74 calls is ok but 25 calls are been made to ViewRoot.draw() in about 3.5 seconds
which means 6 calls for draw every second that is bad.

I want to know why so many calls are made ?

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/qd3" 
        android:layout_height="80px" 
        android:layout_width="156px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="2px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qd2"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_hl_vd_land" 
        android:clickable="true">

        <FrameLayout  
            android:id="@+id/FrameCell3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" >
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/qd3_image" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                    <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/qd_vd_gloss" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/gloss_wt_tr_land"
                    />
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/qd4" 
        android:layout_height="80px" 
        android:layout_width="156px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="2px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_below = "@+id/qd3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qd1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_hl_lp_land" 

        android:clickable="true"
        >

        <FrameLayout  
            android:id="@+id/FrameCell4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_wt_lp_bg_land"></ImageView>

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ></ImageView>

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_wt_lp_num"></ImageView>
                    <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/qd4_image" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lpCountBig"        
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                    
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50sp"                             
                android:paddingTop="17px"
                android:paddingLeft="65px"
            />      
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/lpCountSmall"      
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="38sp"                 
                android:paddingTop="22px"
                android:paddingLeft="57px"
            />      


        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/qd2" 
        android:layout_height="80px" 
        android:layout_width="156px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2px"
        android:layout_toRightOf = "@+id/qd1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_hl_qd2_land"
        android:clickable="true">
        <FrameLayout  
            android:id="@+id/FrameCell4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/qd_time" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/divider_wt_qd_land"
                     />
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/qd_time_gloss" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/gloss_wt_tl_land"
                     />

        </FrameLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/qd_time"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
            android:orientation="vertical" >            

                    <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/mDataOne"      
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_gravity="right"                  
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="44sp"                 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingRight="8px"
                android:paddingTop="2px"
                 />                 
                <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/mDataFive"         
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="right"                  
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="44sp"                 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingRight="8px"
                android:paddingTop="2px"
                     />         
                     <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/mDataSeven"        
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_gravity="right"                  
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="44sp"                 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingRight="8px"
            android:paddingTop="2px"
                     />     

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/qd_pc_sp"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >   


                        <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/mDataTwo"      
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_gravity="right"                  
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="44sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingTop="43px"   
                android:paddingRight="8px"              
                         />

                        <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/mutOne" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"  
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/mDataTwo"
                android:paddingLeft="10px"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/qd1" 
        android:layout_height="80px" 
        android:layout_width="156px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/qd2"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_hl_qd1_port" 
        android:clickable="true">

        <FrameLayout  
            android:id="@+id/FrameCell1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/btn_wt_bl_land" >
            <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/qd1_image" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/map_signal_sought" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/map_wt_overlay_default_land"
                    android:clickable="true"/>

                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/map_seeking_signal" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     />

                     <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/map_gloss" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/gloss_wt_bl_land"
                     />


        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout  
            android:id="@+id/FrameCellMap"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        >
             <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/map_gloss" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/gloss_wt_bl_land"
                     />

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/qd4_hr" 
        android:layout_height="80px" 
        android:layout_width="156px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="2px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_below = "@+id/qd3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qd1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_hl_lp_land"           
        android:clickable="true"
        >

            <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/qd4_image_z" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
            <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/qd4_image_divider" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/divider_wt_qd_land"
            />
                    <FrameLayout  
            android:id="@+id/FrameCell1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

            >
         <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/curzValue"         
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="46sp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:paddingRight="8px"

                android:layout_marginBottom="32px"
                                 /> 

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/curzName"      
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="38sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:paddingRight="8px"

                                 /> 

        </FrameLayout>
    <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/curz"      
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/hr_z_cardio"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10px"
                android:paddingBottom="5px"
                                 /> 
        <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/qd_lp_gloss" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/gloss_wt_br_land"
                     />

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/gUpDown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_wt_z_ad_lg"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mControls"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/m" />
</RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tWtCons"
          android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/st_wt" />
</RelativeLayout>
```